# Redirect the WordPress plugin after submitting button is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a WordPress registration plugin, what i want is when the user is successfully registered, redirect him/her to a Thank you page

Here is my button code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
header("location.href="http://www.getgometro.com/thank-you/");

wp_redirect( 'http://www.getgometro.com/thank-you/' );
exit;

wp_redirect("/www.getgometro.com/thank-you/", 303);
}  
?>
```

None of the above is working

Comment: `header("Location: http://www.getgometro.com/thank-you/");` maybe? And your question is?

Comment: There is syntax error in your header. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: @Rizier123 it display this message: ** Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:52)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
  { ?>

<script>
window.location="http://www.getgometro.com/thank-you/";
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

This is not a proper solution .You need to read this [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;"$yourLink"'>
```

where $yourLink contain link address to which you want to redirect user.