# Redirect after button is click on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When user click the button, php code is executed. After that, the page is refresh. Here is my code.

```
<?php
}
//If click on button 
if (isset($_POST['deliver_confirmation']))
                    {
                       //Update payment meta of deliver_status
                       $meta['deliver_status']= 'Đã giao';
                       edd_update_payment_meta( $payment->ID, '_edd_payment_meta', $meta);
                       //REFRESH CURRENT PAGE CODE HERE
                       //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />';//DOES NOT WORK
                    }


?>
```

Please tell me how can I refresh, or redirect to current page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect the WordPress plugin after submitting button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544911/redirect-the-wordpress-plugin-after-submitting-button-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header("Refresh:0"); // To Refresh
```

or

```
header('Location: http://www.test.com/'); // To Redirect
```

Comment: I got this warning and the page is not refresh. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:172) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\easy-digital-downloads\templates\shortcode-receipt.php on line 290

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this Line:

```
echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';
```